# C# Excel Interop: how can I "get" a table that is already in a worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

My worksheet has a number of tables. I need to manipulate one in particular. Of course I could simply look at its cell numbers and manipulate it cell by cell, but is there any "get" function to "get" the table programatically?

And if so, how would I then manipulate the cells? Is there a command to "get" the entire header, or an entire column by its header (rather than its column number)/

If anyone knows of a guide that explains this, that would be sufficient. I tried googling it but all the results are about database tables, i.e. populating a spreadsheet from a DB.

Answer (score 5):

Swift, I'm working on something similar and I ran across [this article](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp) which helped me.

In short, references to tables can be found in a worksheets list objects.  Iterating through the list object and requesting the range or datarange should get you what you need.

I also found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637097%28v=office.11%29.aspx#odc_office2007_taWorkingwithListsTablesPart1_CheckingSeeWhetherActiveCellinTableorList) which has very similar info.

All these examples are in VBA or VB but I found it not to difficult to port over.

-M

Answer (score 1):

When you say a table, I assume you mean a range. The following code will get a range from within an VS2010 Excel Add-In -

```
Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
Excel.Range myRange = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "D20");
```

Comment: Craig,
I was referring to a table of the kind on the "insert" tab, that allows you to style a block of related cells, assign header rows and total rows, etc. Since you can name the tables I assumed they would be objects that can be manipulated.
Your code will be sufficient for the job. The only drawback is that if the table moves or changes size, I will have to change the code.